# For an app that interacts with the native contacts, is it better to copy all the data in the native book into my app's database?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application, I need to display all the native contacts in a `UITableView`, and search/filter this list quickly enough for an auto-complete function. Can this be done entirely through the native API (using `ABAddressRef`s  etc.), or is it better to run through the native list once (maybe at application startup), copy the data into custom objects and store them in an indexed data structure in memory (or in a searchable database)?

Comment: Are you asking us to experiment for you? My guess is that you don't want to copy. What if that address book changes after your app launches. For example, iCloud pushes changes to your phone in the background.

Comment: No, I'm actually asking you to help me convince a coworker that there's a simpler way, although I'm also willing to be convinced otherwise myself. Right now the app has a very long startup time because of this copying.